# Possibility of achieving magnetic levitation(Arduino) with just one solenoid and a ring magnet?

Tags: arduino, coil, magnetics, electromagnetic, electromagnet

I am currently working on a magnetic levitation project and have been looking into all types of magnetic levitation. One particular video I found around the subject was this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgWHu28xXuQ Which basically levitates a magnet with only one solenoid and a ring of neodymium magnets around it. He used this code for his Arduino:

```
int set_point = 400;  // change
int sensorPin = A0;
int output_pin = 3;
int sensorValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(output_pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
      sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
        //Serial.println(sensorValue);
      if( sensorValue <= set_point)
      digitalWrite(output_pin, LOW);
      else
      digitalWrite(output_pin, HIGH);
```

And successfully managed to get an object to levitate. Well, I tried something similar, I used a 644 turned 120m Copper Coil with a Ferrite (Nickel Zinc) core measuring to be 10mm Diameter and 50mm Height.
Coil Height: 55.00mm
Coil Diameter: 54.00mm
Measured coil inductance with the ferrite core was 49.6mH (21.6mH at its base without a core). Magnets that were used in a ring formation were these magnets: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B074C79DJS/

Tried the code and the schematic as shown in the video, and it failed. Was I just supposed to use a stronger core? Or is this type of system just generally unstable? As just putting any magnetic object near the electromagnet did nothing. There was a hall effect sensor (ss496a) detecting a nearby magnetic field but the solenoid would do nothing unless it was about 1 cm close to it, and even then, it would just pull it to the core and nothing else.

I have tried finding answers in this field, but have ended up with people either doing this with raw components (which I cannot do as I am supposed to use an Arduino) and people discussing about iron cores, which for some reason I cannot find on any market.

Comment: So, are you saying the video is giving wrong or misleading information or, are you doing something that the video is not doing? God forbid that any video on the web may give false or incorrect information.

Comment: Your coil is completely different to his. Assuming you've copied everything else correctly that would seem to be the likely cause.

Comment: Likely so, I did some further research on the subject and saw most systems utilizing a four solenoid system for "equal spread" of the force. Though what I'm now confused on is how to decide for the strength of the magnet on the sides, as I have calculated total strength ejected from four 420 turn coils to withstand weights > 0.5kg, basically more than enough to support the magnetic weight on top of it. I'm not sure if these side magnets should be overtly strong or just normal but very close.